# slash command failed with the error "dispatch_failed"

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

slash command is successfully giving out result but giving error afterwards "dispatch failed"

I am using socket mode but still the issue is coming.

Tried using multiple channels but still the issue persists

Comment: did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to enable the socket mode for the app. Go to your app's configuration and turn on socket mode as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

I have also had the same error, but after this setting I was able to fix the issue.